# Fire is way too bright

Tags: texturing, materials, smoke-simulation

I have not done much but setting the emitter and container in the Physics as flow (as fire & smoke) and domain. Yet, the fire is way too bright nearly white on the bottom (no red flares).
I have searched answers for a day and night, trying nearly every possible button on the Physics, Texture, Material and Lamp. (I also set up Color in Texture. However, nothing works to improve the flares. Can anyone please help?

[image: fire sim in 3D view]

Comment: A screen shot example as well as node setup would assist in figuring out your problem. Remember that Blender is scene referred meaning that bright pixels can be much brighter than the rest of the scene. When this occurs the color is clipped for display. You may have to alter the color management curve in the scene display properties.

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is that you are viewing in the solid viewport. The fire texture only is visible in the rendered viewport.